# Getting error trying to do a customized arraylist with filter

Tags: android, list, filter

I'm building a sectioned list with filter, where, when I filter, the sections headers remain in the results, even if their section is empty.
I based my sectioned list code on [this link](http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/), and it works perfectly (in the end of the page there is a download of the eclipse project), I copied the layout files and the getView() function from this code, and when I run the code, it's ok, when I filter with a empty search, it also works fine, but when I try to filter with anything that actually changes the list, I get an error and the program closes.
My code is below:

```
public class ListaCustom extends ArrayAdapter<Item> implements Filterable{
    private List<Item> items;
    private Filter filter= null;
    private final Object mLock = new Object();
    private ArrayList<Item> mOriginalValues;
    private LayoutInflater vi;
    private int mFieldId = 0;

    public ListaCustom(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        items = objects;

        vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItemNormal(String nome){
        items.add(new ItemNormal(nome));
    };
    public void addSecao(String nome){
        items.add(new Secao(nome));
    };
    public Item get(int pos){
        return items.get(pos);
    };
    public int size(){
        return items.size();
    };

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        final Item i = items.get(position);
            if(i.isSection()){
                Secao si = (Secao)i;
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);

                v.setOnClickListener(null);
                v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
                v.setLongClickable(false);

                final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
                sectionView.setText(si.getNome());
            }else{
                ItemNormal ei = (ItemNormal)i;
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_entry, null);
                final TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);

                if (title != null) 
                    title.setText(ei.getNome());
            }
        return v;
    }



    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
        if(filter == null)
            filter = new myFilter();
        return filter;
    }

    private class myFilter extends Filter{

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                synchronized (mLock) {
                    mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<Item>(items);
                }
            }

            if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                synchronized (mLock) {
                    ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>(mOriginalValues);
                    results.values = list;
                    results.count = list.size();
                }
            } else {
                String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();

                final ArrayList<Item> values = mOriginalValues;
                final int count = values.size();
                final ArrayList<Item> newValues = new ArrayList<Item>(count);

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    final Item value = values.get(i);
                    final String valueText = value.getNome().toLowerCase();

                    // First match against the whole, non-splitted value
                    if (value.isSection()) {
                        newValues.add(value);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (valueText.contains(prefixString)) {
                            newValues.add(value);
                        }   
                    }

                }

                results.values = newValues;
                results.count = newValues.size();
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            Log.v("count", results.count+"");
            items = (List<Item>) results.values;
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Since I am from Brazil, there are some methods and variables in portuguese, so, just to help a little:
Item - abstract class
ItemNormal - extends Item, is a regular item
secao - extends Item, is a section item
getNome() - returns the item text

I don't have idea of what is wrong with this, I'm starting to think that there is something to do with the getView, but I'm really not sure.

I've uploaded my project to [this link](http://www.4shared.com/file/yf8yGn7m/ListaCustomFiltravel.html?) and, if I manage to get a solution, I will update it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Damn it, I overrided the getCount method and it worked. 
I read in a forum, they gave this advice, but I still don't understand when is this method called. If anyone could answer me, I would at least learn something out of this.
thanks anyway

And here is the [link to the working code](http://www.4shared.com/file/VWgzaZ4K/ListaCustomFiltravel_2.html?)